# How to change value of the output reponse message obtained from a backend API

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I got to do a exercise of calling a message from a backend API whereas the message is "Hello world" and transforming the output to Hello Home. I have done the first part of calling an backend api successfully,

**what I have to do is, I have to change the output message from "Hello world" TO "Hello Home"**.

backend api link http://www.mocky.io/v2/59f60737310000550860026a

Answer (score 0):

you can use a payload factory mediator[1] to update the response.

[1]-https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/payloadFactory-Mediator/